# if child class needs to change parent class id.

Tags: asp.net, linq

i am using dbml file to generate class objects
organisation have employees 
now if employee changes organisation
then without removing old organisation 
how to insert new organisation

i have used

```
org=new organisation();
org.Name=xyz;
db.Organisations.InsertOnSubmit(org);
emp.OrgID=org.OrgID;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

but it shows orgID 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code write **db.SubmitChanges()** before  **emp.OrgID=org.OrgID**

```
org=new organisation();
org.Name=xyz;
db.Organisations.InsertOnSubmit(org);
db.SubmitChanges();

emp.OrgID=org.OrgID;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: thanks i havnt thought about multiple db.submitchanges()

Answer (score 0):

Shoudln't this work? Create a new organization object, attach it to the employee and reset the OrgId, then they should be both added when you call submitchanges.

```
var newOrg = new organization();
newOrg.Name = "xyz";
emp.Org = newOrg;
emp.OrgID = 0;
db.SubmitChanges();
```